# Group column values together in one cell

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write an SQL select statement that groups together values from one column into one cell.

e.g.

```
table name: Customer_Hobbies
+------------+------------+-----------+
| CustomerId |     Age    |  Hobby    |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 123        |     17     |  Golf     |
| 123        |     17     |  Football |
| 324        |     14     |  Rugby    |
| 627        |     28     |  Football |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

should return...

```
+------------+------------+----------------+
| CustomerId |     Age    |  Hobbies       |
+------------+------------+----------------+
| 123        |     17     |  Golf,Football |
| 324        |     14     |  Rugby         |
| 627        |     28     |  Football      |
+------------+------------+----------------+
```

Is this possible?

N.B. I know the data's not laid out in a particularly sensible way, but I can't change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `group_concat()`:

```
select customerId, age, group_concat(hobby) as hobbies
from t
group by customerId, age
```

Comment: Sir, you are all kinds of awesome that I cannot even begin to describe.